# How to control scroll chat box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chat

I have an AJAX chat box and i want to control scroll in box

For example when you send new message i made it automatically scroll by setInterval

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#chattingbox").load("msgs.php");
    $("#chattingbox").each( function() 
{
   var scrollHeight = Math.max(this.scrollHeight, this.clientHeight);
   this.scrollTop = scrollHeight - this.clientHeight;
});
}, 2000);
```

but if you scroll up and try to see old messages, it will automatically scroll down so how can i make it automatically only when you already scrolled down and mention in notification if you have new message

here is my code

**HTML**

```
<? require_once ("includes/config.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chatbox">
<div id="hedchatbox">Simple Chat</div>
<div id="hedroomchatbox">
<input type="text" placeholder="yourname" name="name" class="name" >
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="chattingbox">

<?
$select_msgs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM me ORDER BY id ASC limit 20");
$num_msgs = $select_msgs->num_rows;

while ($rows_msgs = $select_msgs->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$id_msgs         = $rows_msgs ['id'];
$username_msgs         = $rows_msgs ['username'];
$text_msgs         = $rows_msgs ['text'];
?>
<div class="message">
<div class="infouser"><? echo $username_msgs; ?></div>
<div class="textmsg"><? echo $text_msgs; ?></div>
</div>
<?
}
?>

</div>
<div id="textareachat">
    <textarea class="textmessage" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
</div>
</div>

<div class="loading"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.textmessage').autosize();

setInterval(function(){
    $("#chattingbox").load("msgs.php");
    $("#chattingbox").each( function() 
{
   var scrollHeight = Math.max(this.scrollHeight, this.clientHeight);
   this.scrollTop = scrollHeight - this.clientHeight;
});
}, 2000);

$("#chattingbox").each( function() 
{
   var scrollHeight = Math.max(this.scrollHeight, this.clientHeight);
   this.scrollTop = scrollHeight - this.clientHeight;
});

$('.textmessage').keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which == 13) {

var name  = $(".name") .val();
var text  = $(".textmessage") .val();

var s = {
"name":name,
"text":text
}

$.ajax({
url:'send_msg.php',
type:'post',
data:s,
beforeSend: function (){
        $(".loading") .show();
        $(".loading") .html("انتظر جارى التحميل....");
        },
success:function(data){
    $(".textmessage").val("");
    $(".loading").html(data);
}
});

return false;  
}
});

});
```

and this is the  **msgs.php**

```
<?php
require_once ("includes/config.php");

$select_msgs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM me ORDER BY id ASC limit 20");
$num_msgs = $select_msgs->num_rows;

while ($rows_msgs = $select_msgs->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$id_msgs         = $rows_msgs ['id'];
$username_msgs         = $rows_msgs ['username'];
$text_msgs         = $rows_msgs ['text'];
?>
<div class="message">
<div class="infouser"><? echo $username_msgs; ?></div>
<div class="textmsg"><? echo $text_msgs; ?></div>
</div>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead on auto-scrolling down ever 2 seconds, you might want to try and scroll down only when your messages window is reloaded. In other words, to modify your AJAX function to something like:

```
success:function(data){
    // Get your backend response first...
    $(".textmessage").val("");
    $(".loading").html(data);
    // ...and only then scroll it down.
    var scrollHeight = Math.max($("#chattingbox").scrollHeight, $("#chattingbox").clientHeight);
    $("#chattingbox").scrollTop = scrollHeight - $("#chattingbox").clientHeight;    
}
```

This solution is not perfect simply because your chat window only seems to be refreshing only when you post something (unless there are portions of JS related to that you're not showing us), but at least it makes more sense usability-wise.

Comment: but if someone send a message the other one cant see it

Comment: Like I said, your chat window doesn't seem to be refreshed until you post something yourself - unless there's some other JavaScript that takes care of it and that you're not showing us. Right now, it just scrolls down every 2 seconds for no apparent reason.

Comment: i know but if he post something it will not scroll down even if i already on the box bottom

Comment: If he posts something you won't even be able to see it until you decide to post something yourself. In this case, the window will be scrolled down as per my suggestion. I really don't know how to explain this any clearer.